# Неправильно определяет переменную temp(индекс наименьшего элемента в строке)

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

В функции **coppi** неправильно определяет переменную temp(минимальный индекс в строке).
Суть задачи: удалить минимальный элемент строки в нечетной строке.

````
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void inputRowsCols(int* rows) {
    printf("Enter the number of elements of the first array 'Row' ");
    while (scanf_s("%d", rows) != 1 || *rows <= 0 || getchar() != ('\n')) {
        printf("Enter the number of elements of the first array 'Row' \a");
        rewind(stdin);
    }
}

int** Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    int** arr;
    arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));//+
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(rows, sizeof(int));
    }
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти");//ошибка выделения памяти
        return 0;
    }
    return arr;
}

int cols(int** arr, int row) {
    int cols = 1;
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        if (arr[row][i] != 0) {
            cols++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return cols;
}

void printMatrix(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols(arr, i); j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != 0)
                printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void input_Matrix(int** arr, int rows, int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int breakk = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < *cols && breakk == 0; j++) {
            printf("Input arr[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            while (scanf_s("%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
                if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                printf("Enter element, row: %d, cols: %d ->", i + 1, j + 1);
                rewind(stdin);
            }
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                breakk = 1;
                if (i != rows - 1) {
                    printf("Next row->\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                (*cols)++;
                arr[i] = (int*)realloc(arr[i], (*cols) * sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
}

void coppi(int** arr, int rows, int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < (*cols); j++) {
            if (arr[temp] > arr[j]) {
                temp = j;
            }
        }
        (*cols)--;
        printf("%d", temp);
        for (int j = temp; j < (*cols); j++) {
            printf("%d", j);
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j + 1];
        }
        arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], (*cols) * sizeof(int));
    }
        else {
            continue;
        }
}


}


int main() {


    int rows = 1, cols = 1;
    inputRowsCols(&rows);

    int** arr = Matrix(rows, &cols);
    input_Matrix(arr, rows, &cols);

    printf("\n\nYour matrix -> \n");
    printMatrix(arr, rows);

    coppi(arr, rows, &cols);

    printf("\n\nNew matrix -> \n");
    printMatrix(arr, rows);

   
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: индекс строки забыли `if (arr[i][temp] > arr[i][j]) {`

Comment: Оно все равно неправильно определяет.

Comment: Еще заметил то, что  у меня немного не те элементы массива берутся

Comment: Берется то, чего вовсе не было задано

Comment: Знаете, количество вопросов с `coppi` уже вынуждает просить вас дать **полное** и точное задание, чтоб сделать его один раз, и закрыть эти все вопросы... Что от вас требуется — только всю задачу, пожалуйста...